# HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable Exchange 2003 OWA

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, exchange-2003, outlook-web-app

Receiving HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable when trying to access exchange web access.
Server 2003 & Exchange 2003
Have tried:

- Deleting virtual directories and rebuilding them in IIS
- Restarting
- Dismounting & mounting the public folder store & mailbox store
- It's not AppPoolQueueLength
- Restarting all services (all proper ones are running)
- Making it use ssl or not (regular http) -- same thing for both
- Installing IIS & exchange 2003 on a new 2003 box as a new FE server, OWA on that gets same error.

Not sure why it's getting a 503... was working without an issue and randomly is stuck at this no matter what; ll users can still successfully connect and use via outlook, only the web access is having issues.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you rebooted the server? What does the Pool Nonpaged Bytes perfmon counter look like?

Comment: Yes, have rebooted it several times; where would one find that?

Comment: Run perfmon and add the Pool Nonpaged Bytes counter from the Memory object. If it's over 100MB then that's likely the problem.

Comment: Seems to be sitting at 59-60 MB (62127500 bytes), so assuming it's not that.

Comment: No, I don't think it is based on those numbers. Unfortunately I don't have any other ideas. Sorry.

Comment: What is the Windows 2003 Service pack being applied? Can you reinstall the latest service pack and check again? Also, can you check the application and the system logs by going to start->run-eventvwr